# Having trouble navigation draw pre made repeats the 1st selected item again and again

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have used navigation draw activity of android studio ,my problem is when my app starts its show the 1st item selected  activity by default and also repeats the same activity again and again on pressing    **"<-"** arrow icon also
I have put on select of 1st item of list to start diff activity but this activity gets repeated again n again 
code is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
  // Selectitem(position);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();


}








public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);

            startActivity(new Intent(this, extView.class));

            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

**And my 2nd activity code is :**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_view);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       /* modelItems = new Model[5];
        modelItems[0] = new Mdel("pizza", 0);
        modelItems[1] = new Model("burger", 1);
        modelItems[2] = new Model("olives", 1);
        modelItems  [3] = new Model("orange", 0);
        modelItems[4] = new Model("tomato", 1);*/
        initView();
    }
    private void initView() {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

        String url = "http://100.76.231.151/test/apps.php";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_text_view, menu);


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Model> data) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        Log.i("extView", "values = <<" + data + ">>");
        CustomAdaptor adapter = new CustomAdaptor(this, data);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: My 1st  item gets selected my default n execute reaptedly??